# When size is 64 bits then why shifting left 32 times give a zero

Tags: c

```
unsigned long long n=123;
printf("size of n:%d\n",sizeof(n)); //output of this line is "size of n:8"
n=n<<32;
printf("%u",n); //output of this line is "0"
```

why output is 0 when the size is 64bits
output 0 is justified only if size is 32bits

Comment: because the printf format is incorrect.

Comment: Because `%u` prints an `unsigned` and not an `unsigned long long`.  Use `%llu` instead.

Comment: debug your program you'll get a non-zero value. From memory: `%llu` should do it.

Answer (score 4):

`n` may be 64 bits, but your `printf()` call only expects 32 bits. This is undefined behavior. What appears to be happening in this particular case is that the remaining bits are cut off, and only the apparently low order 32 bits are displayed. Other platforms/compilers/machines might do something entirely different.

You can fix that by passing the correct integer type in the format string:

```
printf("%llu",n);
```

Comment: You don't mind my edit? This is so I can upvote this helpful answer in clear conscience.

Comment: You have adequate disclaimers so this answer is upvote material.

Answer (score 4):

The program behaviour is undefined on two counts, and you're on thin ice on another point:

1. Use `"%zu"` as the format specifier for the `sizeof` return type. Using `'%d'` wreaks havoc, particularly if you pass multiple arguments to `printf`.
2. `unsigned long long` is *at least* 64 bits. That doesn't matter in your case but don't assume it's *always* 64 bits. And the format specifier needs to be `%llu`.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: "zd" doesn't work on Windows unless you enable built-in gcc printf.

Comment: Microsoft has its own implementation of `printf` (and it sucks). gcc relies on it unless you enable some compilation directive (use builtin printf that kind of crap)

Comment: keeping aside the issues of printf(). does the back end mathematics will effect the results ? Because I am using n as a 64bit number in my code.

Comment: @MuhammadFuzail: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The only hazard with an ull type is a potential division by zero.